# Clojure Spec - Issue with spec/or nested in spec/and

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I've recently been trying out Clojure Spec and ran into an unexpected error message.  I've figured out that if you have a spec/or nested in a spec/and then the spec functions, after the spec/or branch, get passed a conformed value rather than the top level value.

You can see this in the printed value of "v" here (contrived example):

```
(spec/valid? (spec/and (spec/or :always-true (constantly true))
                       (fn [v]
                         (println "v:" v)
                         (constantly true)))
         nil)
v: [:always-true nil]
=> true
```

I think this may be intentional from the doc string of spec/and:

> Takes predicate/spec-forms, e.g.
>
> (s/and even? #(< % 42))
>
> Returns a spec that returns the conformed value. **Successive
>    conformed values propagate through rest of predicates.**

But this seems counterintuitive to me as it would hamper reuse of spec predicates, because they'd need to be written to accept "[<or branch> <actual value>]".

Things get even worse if you have multiple spec/or branches:

```
(spec/valid? (spec/and (spec/or :always-true (constantly true))
                       (spec/or :also-always-true (constantly true))
                       (fn [v]
                         (println "v:" v)
                       (constantly true)))
         nil)
v: [:also-always-true [:always-true nil]]
=> true
```

Have I missed something fundamental here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But this seems counterintuitive to me as it would hamper reuse of spec predicates

IMO the alternatives to these behaviors are less appealing:

- Discard `s/or`'s conformed tags *by default*. We can always discard it if we want, but we wouldn't want clojure.spec to make that decision for us. Spec assumes we *want to know* which `s/or` branch matched.
- Don't flow conformed values in `s/and`, at the expense of spec/predicate composability.

Luckily we can discard the `s/or` tags if necessary. Here are two options:

- Wrap the `s/or` in `s/noncomforming`. Thanks to glts' comment below reminding me about this (undocumented) function!

  ```
  (s/valid?
    (s/and
      (s/nonconforming (s/or :s string? :v vector?))
      empty?)
    "")
  => true
  ```
- `s/and` the `s/or` specs with a `s/conformer` that discards the tag.

  ```
  (s/valid?
    (s/and
      (s/and (s/or :s string? :v vector?)
             ;; discard `s/or` tag here
             (s/conformer second))
      empty?)
    [])
  => true
  ```

  If you often needed this, you could reduce boilerplate with a macro:

  ```
  (defmacro dkdc-or [& key-pred-forms]
    `(s/and (s/or ~@key-pred-forms) (s/conformer second)))
  ```

> Things get even worse if you have multiple spec/or branches

If you're writing a spec for data that allows for *alternatives* (e.g. `s/or`, `s/alt`), and you're "flowing" valid alternatives into subsequent predicates (`s/and`), IMO it's more generally useful to have that knowledge in subsequent predicates. I'd be interested in seeing a more realistic use case for this type of spec, because there might be a better way to spec it.

Comment: You can also use `s/nonconforming` instead of the conformer.

Comment: Taylor it is a pleasure to read your answers, always _real_ answers with a rationale instead of the quick and dirty piece of code that might solve the question but doesn't contribute to understanding. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for a taking the time to write a great answer.  I understand your points but ultimately I can see this tripping up a lot of people who start small, building up spec's with simple predicates and then, as I found, they will stop working when you try to combine them with the and/or operations.  Perhaps this is a case for simple and/or's that would work as you'd expect with simple predicates and a more advanced option for cases where the conformed result is needed?

Answer (score 0):

Complementary comment: the behavior of Spec spotted by the question means that you can very well have `(and (s/valid? ::spec-1 v) (s/valid? ::spec2) v)` but not `(s/valid? (s/and ::spec-1 ::spec-2) v)`, due to conforming from `::spec-1`.

You might understandably find this behavior of `s/and` surprising (not to mention insane). Note however that you *will* have `(s/valid? (s/and (s/nonconforming ::spec-1) ::spec-2) v)`, as mentioned by the accepted answer.

The corollary is that **when using `s/and`, ask yourself whether you need `s/conforming`.** This piece of advice might be a worthwhile addition to the docstring of `s/and`.